# How can I get more decimal from Coinbase API?

Tags: python, decimal, coinbase-api

The python API code,

client.get_buy_price(currency_pair = 'XRP-EUR')

gives me the XRP amount as  only "0.25".

How can I see more decimal, like 0.25126453?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason in the python API, get_buy_price(...) and get_sell_price(...) only give 2 decimals, but if you use get_spot_price(...) you will get more decimals

Answer (score 0):

I use this query and i get 4 digits

```
response = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/XRP-EUR/spot")
data = response.json()
pricebuy= data["data"]["amount"]

Print(f"Current Price: {pricebuy}")
```

Terminalshow 4 decimals.

Current Price: 0.5627